# Function to look through folder and use a wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery

been a lurker on Stack Overflow for a while, love the site.

Now its my turn. From the code below, i am making the background image random each time the page loads.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me make this more efficient so that i don't have to manually enter my filenames ? Im looking for some kind of wildcard function that can look through my given folder and load footer*.png or even *.png as this folder will only contain footer patterns.

```
var images = ['footer.png', 'footer2.png', 'footer3.png'];

$('#footer').css({'background-image': 'url(images/footers/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

Comment: You can't read folders with Javascript. You need a server side language such as PHP to read the folder and write out all the filenames for your javascript code.

Comment: What are you using on server side (RoR, Asp.net MVC, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP, you can do it:

```
<?php

$directory = "./images/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.png");

foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo $image . "\n";
}

?>
```

Just don't make `$directory` an arbitrary argument, as the Russian hackers will jack your webapp.

To use it, make an AJAX request to the PHP file and parse the output, separating each file by the `\n` character.

So with jQuery,

```
var images = [];

jQuery.load('images.php', function(data)
{
  images = data.split('\n');
});
```

Comment: Good to warn against the Russians!

Comment: Lol, being one, I find it to be an honor ;)